# Accessing the session object after a POST

Tags: node.js, node.js-connect

I'm using express.js with the `session` middleware. This is my code:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express.createServer();

app.configure(function () {
   app.use(express.cookieParser())
      .use(express.session({ secret: 'blabla' }));
});

app.post('/login', function (request, response) {
    console.log(request.session); // Prints `undefined`
});
```

How can I access the `session` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exact code with `app.listen()` appended works for me. Make sure you're using the latest express. I tried on express v2.5.1 and node v0.6.5.